# How to set a huge head allocate array as specific float number C++

Tags: c++, memset

At first, I allocate a huge block memory by using Intel Math Kernel Library API. After that I want to set this array as specific value, for example 1234.5678. I plan to use the `void* memset( void* dest, int ch, std::size_t count );` function, but it seems that this function can only set int value. I can use the simple for loop to solve this problem. However, I think it is not very efficient to use `for loop` to set initial value for a such huge block. So my question is

1. Do I have another way to initialize such huge block memory without using `for loop`

Comment: To make sure I understand, you want to set the value of *every array element* to `1234.5678` for example? If so, you'll probably want to use [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) or [`std::fill_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n)

Comment: Why do you think a for loop will be inefficient. Have you tried it and found it to be too slow? Compilers are very good at optimising the code you write. Basically the first choice should be to write the most straightforward code and let the compiler do the optimising for you.

Comment: @john You can compare the performance between memset and for loop if you want to set the value to some integer number. You will find the bit operation is much faster. What's more, if you use the for loop, you have to pay the cost to check the termination condition. So I just want to see if there is another way to do that.

Comment: @CoryKramer I think the two functions can only work well for contains which define iterator.

Comment: @Sean Well, you said that it is an array. And the language specifies iterator for arrays. It is a pointer.

Comment: @Sean But you want a floating point number, so memset is not an option. And more than likely `std::fill_n` is just a different way of writing a for loop.

Comment: @Sean `What's more, if you use the for loop, you have to pay the cost to check the termination condition.` So does `std::memset`. You'll find that a decently OK compiler will replace a bare loop (or indeeed `std::fill`) with a call to `std::memset` (when applicable). That said, `std::memset` cannot be used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::fill_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) to assign a value to each value of your array

```
#include <algorithm>

std::fill_n(data, count, 1234.5678);
```

Note that many compilers will generate the same code even if you use a raw for loop

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    data[i] = 1234.5678;
}
```

See this [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/j88wLi) example, in both cases the above generate identical assembly code

```
void fill_a(double *,unsigned __int64) PROC                         ; fill_a
$LN14:
        sub     rsp, 8
        test    rdx, rdx
        je      SHORT $LN6@fill_a
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], rdi
        mov     rax, 4653144502051863213      ; 40934a456d5cfaadH
        mov     rdi, rcx
        mov     rcx, rdx
        rep stosq
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp]
$LN6@fill_a:
        add     rsp, 8
        ret     0
```

Comment: I use mkl to allocate memory and I do not think there should be a iterator.

Comment: @Sean As long as you have (or can cast to) `double*` that *is* an iterator

Answer (score 0):

> I plan to use the void* memset( void* dest, int ch, std::size_t count ); function, but it seems that this function can only set int value.

You can actually use memset to set the value of floats<sup>1</sup>, or indeed any trivially copyable type. The `int ch` is simply the value of the byte that will be copied over the data.

This however does mean that you cannot use memset to set just any arbitrary value for multi-byte types because all bytes will be repeated. You can for example set integer to 0 which is four 0 bytes, or a four byte integer to 4369 which is four 1 bytes.

In case of 32 bit IEEE 754 conforming float, you can memset to the value 785.066650391F for example, by doing this: `std::memset(ptr, count * sizeof(float), 0x44)`. This is because that particular number consists of four repeated 0x44 bytes.

> specific value, for example 1234.5678

This specific value doesn't consist of repeated bytes, so it cannot be created with memset.

> I can use the simple for loop to solve this problem

Correct.

> However, I think it is not very efficient to use for loop to set initial value for a such huge block

You may be surprised to find out how good compilers are at optimising loops. Sometimes they replace a loop with call to memset (when it would have same result); other times they result in faster code than the call to memset would be (well, in theory at least. Compilers also know what memset does, and can also replace call to it with inline code that would have been generated from the loop, if it thinks that it might be faster).

You don't need to write the loop yourself however. As [Cory Kramer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62305693/2079303) shows, the standard library has an algorithm for this.

---

<sup>1</sup> With the caveat that the language standard does not specify the bit-representation of floating point types, so the resulting value could technically be meaningless or even a trap representation. On the other hand IEEE 754 is fairly ubiquitous, and you may be able to rely on it depending on use case.